# Is this line in the SpaceX livestream engine exhaust?

Tags: spacex, iss, crs-30

In the [livestream of the recent mission CRS-30 from SpaceX](https://www.spacex.com/launches/mission/?missionId=crs-30), one could see a vertical line going up. However in other camera shots it was not visible. Was this line the engine exhaust or was there some kind of object infront of the camera? Also why was it not visible from the other cameras?

Camera view where the line is visible:
[image]

Camera view where the line is invisible:[image]

Comment: @uhoh I am not sure why the link does not work, but maybe this one works for you. https://x.com/SpaceX/status/1770517564118212761?s=20

Comment: Thanks! The link in your question works for me now. Earlier, I just got a blank black page. I was traveling in a different country using a local SIM card for data and possibly it was either blocked or loading was too slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At T+2:50 it's particularly apparent from the motion of the mark in question against the limb of the Earth that the mark is fixed to the camera lens. It's a smudge or scratch.

Comment: Good catch. Other clues are that the two camera views are pointed in the same direction, just from opposite sides of the MVac engine (apparently they are watching for even cooling of the nozzle). If this was an exhaust trail it should be visible in both views (as pointed out by the OP). Also the streak is still in view much later, for example at  T+9 after orbit insertion.  But your observation is conclusive.